# QGIS 3.4 handle bad layers and PostGIS views

Tags: qgis, postgis

My project contains several views from PostGIS (2.3). I had to update them and now the Handle Bad Layers window shows for just three of them.
I checked the data source and the query after `table=...` is the same in PostGIS. I have just added a primary key in the views with `row_number() over()`. I removed it and load the project again without success.
By the way, I noticed that in this last case (removing pk), the data source in the project is not updated so I edited the .qgs to do it. There it is the same stored in the project and in PostGIS. It seems to have no effect.

The layers have many styles and the project many layouts so you can imagine the pain if I can't fix the data source issue.